# Connecting flash to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I have a mysql database thats all set up on a wamp server on my comp and I have writen a simple PHP file that will return an XML with all the data in the database in it to flash.  However whenever I run my code to load this XML flash tells me that it wont communicate with an internet enabled location. I have tried a cross domain policy like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

but that doesnt seem to work either... Any help on this?

Comment: What method are you using to communicate with PHP?

Comment: I found a tutorial that told me how to right a php that will produce an xml when executed containing the information from my mysql database. In flash I am just loading it like a normal xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your local drives as trusted locations on [Adobe's Global Settings Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)

[image]

Comment: I have added my server locations to that box, how do I add my drivers

Comment: Add your local drives, as in your entire C:\ - If the SWF is running on that drive. I have 3 drives I have added. C, D and E as I might develop in such a manner where a SWF might be executed on either of those.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Publish Settings and change "Local playback security" to "Access network only" and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I have done that and now I have this error:

Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///C|/Users/Sparky/Desktop/Number%20Guessing%20Game/ProjectX.swf cannot load data from http://localhost/phpmyadmin/woodhouse.students.php.
 at Main()[C:\Users\Sparky\Desktop\Number Guessing Game\Main.as:20]

I think I get what it means but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: I copied and pasted that from the address bar at the top like the other examples I found. I have a cross domain file but im not sure if its right ot if i am using it right... there isnt much on the internet that covers this from start to finish